# Bootstrap 4 - Need Collapse to Adjust Masonry Layout

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, cycle2

**Solution:**

Solved swapping Cycle2 for a similar slideshow script that's responsive.

[Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taylovision/uq5z29yh/)

```
     (function($) {

  var $carousel = $('.carousel'),
            $masonry    = $('#cards');

    $carousel.on('afterChange', function(slick){

        $masonry.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.card-item'
        }).on('shown.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
            $masonry.masonry();
        });

    }).slick({
        arrows: false,
        speed: 0,
        infinite: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 400
    });

})(jQuery);
```

**Original Question:**

I have taken the card-column "masonry" from bootstrap 4 and adapted it to work with masonry js - they only supported B3 from what I could find - minus the gutters.

I'm putting in a collapse link and that's where the issue is. I can't get the grid-item to push it's container down, which would reformat the masonry layout - I think I worded that correctly.

It currently shows and hides fine, but the layout remains the same so it ends up showing under other elements instead of keeping the masonry layout.

Stripped all my solutions out so the fiddle is purely layout out this point.

[jsfiddle here](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

I feel like it should involve the following, but no luck. :[

```
$grid.on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
  $grid.masonry('layout');
});
```

Essentially, when the collapse is open, keep layout in tact, but I can't translate it to the code properly.

Another attempt was to merge bootstrap events with the masonry layout. I couldn't get it to work, though.

```
$('.collapsing').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  // do something…
  $grid.masonry('layout');
});
```

Fiddle has both of these included.

I think I need something that reads more like

> 1. What is the container size at closed
> 2. What is it at open
> 3. Change layout to size at open

Not sure how to write the code for it. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `.on` method

```
(function ($) {

    var $masonry = $('#cards');
    $masonry.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.card-item'
    }).on('shown.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
        $masonry.masonry();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

See working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/ax1d7ok6/

The only issue with this is that masonry will never naturally animate with the bootstrap collapse method, masonry will only fire once the bootstrap collapse is complete. Bummer I know :-(

Comment: I've not changed any external sources from your fiddle bro :-)

Comment: Buttons threw me off. Let me implement and see how it handles. I think this solves the issue fine.

Comment: Sorry I had to rebuild the demo to simplify the html so I could get my head round it. Our methods are the same, bs4 collapse elems within a bs4 card elem inside the masonry container

Comment: Got it working with your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/e5t4uk6b/

Comment: Yours makes use of the parent and works nicely. You actually have better use of the cols too. The code is clean. The only issue I'm having is they load in and some over lap. If I toggle, then they all layout fine. Going to add in the initializing code to see if it resolves.

Comment: Send me another fiddle of your problem if you can, but I gotta dash, good luck man

Comment: Updated original post with the new fiddle.

Comment: Its a bit rough but try this https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/ax1d7ok6/3/ using [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) instead as its responsive and has various callbacks which you might be able to play around with. I've ditched the image loader plugin

Comment: The previous rough fiddle was using `.on('afterChange'` on the carousel `.on` method. This means everytime after the carousel slide changes, masonry re-fires which is a little excessive as masonry will be running constantly. I originally was trying to use slicksliders 'init' callback but because the images would not load in time for new users (incognito), the 'init' callback sometimes ran before the carousel images had loaded. So i've brought back the imagesloaded script which fires masonry once all images have loaded incase the slick 'init' callback runs before...

Comment: ...this is better so masonry is not constantly firing :-) See new fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/q5unok0k/